# Mathf.clamp is not working correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made my own character in Unity, I'm working on the camera right now and I want to clamp  the Y rotation of the Camera, while I'm doing this the correct way.

```
mouseRotY = Mathf.Clamp(mouseRotY, -90.0f, 90.0f);
```

So what just happens is that the camera is rotating from 359 to 0. Nothing happens until I move my mouse up when playing the game. It makes the screen look like it's flickering.

Here's my full code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour {

    CharacterController cc;

    public float baseSpeed = 3.0f;
    public float mouseSensitivity = 1.0f;

    float mouseRotX = 0,
          mouseRotY = 0;

    public bool inverted = false;

    float curSpeed = 3.0f;

    string h = "Horizontal";
    string v = "Vertical";

    void Start () {
        cc = gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {

        curSpeed = baseSpeed;

        mouseRotX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity;
        mouseRotY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;;
        mouseRotY = Mathf.Clamp(mouseRotY, -90.0f, 90.0f);
        if (!inverted)
            mouseRotY *= -1;
        else
            mouseRotY *= 1;

        float forwardMovement = Input.GetAxis(v);
        float strafeMovement = Input.GetAxis(h);

        Vector3 speed = new Vector3(strafeMovement * curSpeed, 0, forwardMovement * curSpeed);
        speed = transform.rotation * speed;



        cc.SimpleMove(speed);
        transform.Rotate(0, mouseRotX, 0);
        Camera.main.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(mouseRotY, 0 ,0); 

    }
}
```

If anyone of you could help me with this, that would be splendid. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inverted logic is flawed, just take it out and it works. To invert the rotation you need to invert only the input and not the rotation itself every frame(it will just go from + to - and back to + again and so on). Here is a stripped down version for the y-rotation with inverted flag that works:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float mouseSensitivity = 1.0f;

    float mouseRotY = 0.0f;

    public bool inverted = false;
    private float invertedCorrection = 1.0f;

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        if(Input.GetAxis ("Fire1") > 0.0f)
            inverted = !inverted;

        if(inverted)
            invertedCorrection = -1.0f;
        else
            invertedCorrection = 1.0f;

        mouseRotY -=  invertedCorrection * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;

        mouseRotY = Mathf.Clamp(mouseRotY, -90.0f, 90.0f);

        Camera.main.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(mouseRotY, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
    }
}
```

another thing you might want to do is get the original rotation of the camera in your Start() function. The way it is now it sets the rotation to zero on the first frame. I cant tell from the script if this is the intended behaviour or not.